# Does the outer class's main method gets called by default in a nested class?

Tags: c#

If I have the following code:

```
class Outer
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    class Inner
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The by default, which main method would be executed, would it be the main method of the outer class?

Also, another question is, what is the difference between a nested inner class and an internal class in C#?

Comment: -1 - Attempting to compile this would yield the obvious answer.  Your "another question" should be asked as another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which main method would be executed, would it be the main method of the outer class?

You'll get a [compiler error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9k01y87.aspx) that the program has more than one entry point defined.

> what is the difference between a nested inner class and an internal class in C#?

**Internal classes** are classes marked with the accessibility modifier `internal`, which are only accessible within the same compilation unit (i.e. assembly), or to other assemblies that [you trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx); a **nested class** is just a class declared inside the scope of another class. They're *orthogonal* concepts.

If a class is not marked with any accessibility modifiers (`internal`, `public`, `protected`, `private`, `protected internal`), it's by default **internal** if it is *top-level* (not nested) or **private** if it is *nested*.

Comment: Thanks. So an internal class is similar to a protected class. What does it mean by the same assembly? Is it the same package/ namespace? Thanks.

Comment: The same assembly is like the same project in Visual Studio, and it's not the same namespace.

Comment: Only a nested class can be `protected`, and it's visible by the subclasses of the containing class, even when they're in different assemblies. It's different than `internal`.

Comment: Thanks! It makes so much sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

An **Inner Class** is a class contained within another class.
An **Internal Class** is a class declared with the `internal` keyword indicating that it is visible only within the current Assembly.

Comment: OK, got it :D I read that an internal class can be accessed by classes in the same assembly. what does it mean by the same assembly? Is it the same package or namespace? Thanks

Comment: An assembly is generally a .DLL or an .EXE. In other words a class library or an executable. Assemblies can have multiple namespaces and namespaces can span multiple assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

If you do nothing, you get a compiler error.  However, you can choose an entry point in the project properties (VS 2010) -> Application tab -> Startup object.